# Getting 404 Page Not Found on refresh, when using parallel routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, vercel

I am creating this webapp dashboard in Next js 13 latest version with app router. it have dashboard and search bar on top. I tried to use parallel routes.
@search folder search bar and page.jsx contains dashboard.
When ever i am using link from side bar it is working properly but if refresh the page it shows 404 Not Found.

[image]

@search folder contains searchbar

[image]

when using with sidebar links it working properly

[image]

but if i am refreshing the page i am getting 404.

[image]

Everything is working flawlessly in component system.

can any help me with this parallel routes.

I am trying to put search bar and dashboard in same page by using parallel routes introduced by nextjs 13. but it is working as expected but not on refresing the page.

I tried component way it is working but i want to use parallel routes for sharing data between server components.

Comment: Why is the folder called `@search`? Please do not share images of code. Replace them with a text-based [mcve]

Comment: to use parallel routes you have to name folder with @ symbol.

Comment: If you want search bar and dashborad on the same page, you should use a layout.js inside that folder. See here for reference https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts#layouts

Comment: This may help you.
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/48090

Answer (score 2):

Try to move all the content inside `@search/page.tsx` to `default.tsx`, and remove the `page.tsx`.

---

#### before

```
@search
- page.tsx
```

other answers may be suggesting

```
@search
- page.tsx
- default.tsx
```

where `default.tsx` could be as simple as

```
export default function Default() {
  return null;
}
```

that could probably fix the 404, however, other grouped pages may won't find `@search/pages.tsx` well. If you don't really need the segmentation, actually you can use `default.tsx` without `page.tsx` as below.

#### after

```
@search
- default.tsx
```

worked for me for both the root route and other sub-grouped routes.